# How to pinging domain in every few seconds/minutes using C#.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dns, httpresponse, ping

I going to developed website that ping domain in every some time interval for checking the domain status. refer site: http://pingdom.com/ this site also like do same. How I get Ping statistic using C#..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Ping class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx)

```
        Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions ();

        // Use the default Ttl value which is 128,
        // but change the fragmentation behavior.
        options.DontFragment = true;

        // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (data);
        int timeout = 120;
        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send (args[0], timeout, buffer, options);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Address: {0}", reply.Address.ToString ());
            Console.WriteLine ("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
            Console.WriteLine ("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
            Console.WriteLine ("Don't fragment: {0}", reply.Options.DontFragment);
            Console.WriteLine ("Buffer size: {0}", reply.Buffer.Length);
        }
```

You can start timer in your Global.asax, and ping you domain in every time interval by using Ping class

Comment: its not Global.aspx its Global.asax

Comment: Oops, fixed @Shekhar_Pro, Thank you

Comment: Are you doing job or personal business?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt where your job going on? nice to meet you.

Comment: I am in Armenia, @Abhishek and you? how works going on in India? :)

Comment: here it is mkrtchyan.arsen at gmail.com @Abhishek

Answer (score 1):

There's a [PING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) class which you can use. You can use Send Method to do the pinging and receive the echo.

```
        Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions ();

        // Use the default Ttl value which is 128,
        // but change the fragmentation behavior.
        options.DontFragment = true;

        // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (data);
        int timeout = 120;
        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send (args[0], timeout, buffer, options);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Address: {0}", reply.Address.ToString ());
            Console.WriteLine ("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
            Console.WriteLine ("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
            Console.WriteLine ("Don't fragment: {0}", reply.Options.DontFragment);
            Console.WriteLine ("Buffer size: {0}", reply.Buffer.Length);
        }
```